# using Twitter gem in rails 3, what needs to go here to share what was posted to twitter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, rubygems

I installed the Twitter gem and I'm trying to allow whatever users post on my site to automatically go to Twitter as well.

When people "post" here's the controller that is used under "create"

```
def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      if @micropost.review
        UserMailer.review_email(@user).deliver
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        flash[:success] = "Post"
        @twitter = Twitter::Client.new
        @twitter.update(**""**)
      redirect_to root_path
    end
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

The above code works if I just use @twitter.update("Hi Twitter"), the "Hi Twitter" gets sent to Twitter which is different from what the user actually posted. I tried micropost.content and some other lines but they threw me errors.

Here's the schema.db

```
create_table "microposts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.string   "image"
```

Here's what the feed on my website looks like but I want to also show on someone's Twitter site

feed_item.html.erb (view)

```
<%= truncate(feed_item.content, :length=>140, :omission=>' ...') %>
<%= link_to feed_item.image.path, feed_item.user if feed_item.image? %>
```

Comment: Have you tried `@micropost.content`? Please post what errors you got.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure @micropost.content contains a string or anything at all? Try:

```
@twitter.update(@micropost.content.to_s)
```

Comment: thanks that worked. is it possible to truncate it down to 140 and show a link to the image.path as well if there's one like it shows on my feed?

Comment: truncate(@micropost.content.to_s, length: 140)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate

and I don't know it would depend on your other data's structure relative to your issue.